# ¿Existe manera de dar click por medio de javascript a un botón que se encuentra en una página llamada con iframe?

Tags: javascript

Ya intenté buscando el texto del botón en la página pero no lo encuentra ya que es un iframe ¿qué hago?

```html
<iframe id="content" src="page.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

si `padre.html` e `hijo.html` están en el mismo `protocolo://dominio:puerto`

`padre.html`

```
<iframe id=elIframe src=hijo.html></iframe>
<script>
// referencia a la ventana del iframe
var soyTuHijo = document.getElementById('elIframe').contentWindow;
// cuando carga el contenido
soyTuHijo.onload = function() {
  // buscar el boton en el documento
  var elBoton = soyTuHijo.document.getElementById('elBoton')
  console.log( elBoton )
  elBoton.click();
}
</script>
```

`hijo.html`

```
<button id=elBoton onclick="cliqueado(this)">un boton</button>
<script>
var cliqueado = function( quien ){
  console.log(`cliqueado ${quien.id}`);
}
</script>
```

si `padre.html` e `hijo.html` no están en el mismo `protocolo://dominio:puerto` hay un ejemplo de cómo enviar mensajes entre frames [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/208452/81450)