# Obtener un elemento creado dinamicamente dentro de un <iframe>

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un *scraper*; para ello, cargo la página a examinar dentro de un `<iframe>` y accedo a su `document` para buscar el elemento que me interesa (estoy usando `Electron` que me permite saltarme ciertos elementos de seguridad).

El asunto es que esa página crea una ventana modal de forma dinámica. Tanto desde el propio `Electron` como si uso un explorador *normal*, puedo ver que existe un elemento `<input>` con un `id` en concreto. Y siempre con el mismo `id`, no es generado aleatoriamente.

Sin embargo, en mi código, no consigo localizar dicho `<input>` en el documento a *espiar*. Esta captura es lo que veo en las `DevTools` del propio `Electron` (el `<iframe>` ocupa toda la ventana). Claramente, **existe** un botón con el `id` que busco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la primera versión de mi código:

```
class Scraper {
    constructor( id ) {
        this._iframe = document.getElementById( id );
    }

    async get( ref ) {
        const win = await this.loadBaseUrl( Config.url );
        const doc = win.document;

        Scraper.setReference( win, ref );
    }

    async loadBaseUrl( url ) {
        const self = this;

        return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
            self._iframe.src = Config.url;
            self._iframe.onload = function( ev ) {
                resolve( self._iframe.contentWindow );
            };
            self._iframe.onerror = function( ev ) {
                reject( ev );
            }
        } );
    }

    static setReference( win, text ) {
        const doc = win.document;

        const input = doc.getElementById( "ctl00$Contenido$txtRC2" );
        const button = doc.getElementById( "ctl00_Contenido_btnDatos" );

        input.value = text;
        button.click( );
    }
}
```

No hay forma, al llamar a `Scraper.get( )`, las variables `input` y `button` siempre valen `null` (pese a que, como dije, si existen los elementos con esos `id` en la página).

Entonces caí en la cuenta de que el formulario es dinámico; así que añadí un tiempo de espera antes de buscar los elementos (pausé 5 segundos; la página real tarda bastante menos en mostrar la ventana; no tarda ni 1 segundo):

```
async function sleep( ms ) {
    return new Promise( function( resolve ) {
        setTimeout( resolve, ms );
    } );
}

...
async get( ref ) {
    const win = await this.loadBaseUrl( Config.url );
    const doc = win.document;

    await sleep( 5000 );

    Scraper.setReference( win, ref );
}
```

El resultado fue el mismo: `input` y `button`, ambos, tienen el valor `null`.

He descartado que sea problema de la advertencia sobre *cookies*. Tanto en `Electron` como en un navegador *normal*, aun sin aceptar ni rechazar las *cookies*, la página tiene un comportamiento funcional: rellenando el `<input>`, se realiza la búsqueda.

<sub>**Nota**: La página que estoy intenta *escrapear* es de un organismo estatal: el [buscador oficial del Catastro en España](https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/Cartografia/mapa.aspx?buscar=S)</sub>

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: Te puedo dar unas recomendaciones: (1) Claramente no estas usando la herramienta indicada para resolver el problema, hay librerías para hacer scrapper que lo hace mucho muy sencillo.- (2) El sitio está hecho en ASP.NET hasta donde yo recuerdo las id son autogeneradas y pueden cambiar (a menos que expresamente se hayan puesto como estáticas), lo mejor es que uses otro selector.- (3) quizás es más fácil ir directamente a https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/CYCBienInmueble/OVCBusqueda.aspx?from=NuevoVisor&pest=. -  (4) Prueba const doc = win.contentWindow.document; o const doc = win.contentDocument

Comment: (1) Pero seguro que no sería tan divertido ;-p (2) He comprobado en varios navegadores que siempre es la misma `id` (3) La idea es interpretar los resultados de la búsqueda para guardarlos en archivos Excel por *paquetes*, conteniendo varios resultados.

Comment: (2) El tema de las Id en asp.net no dependen del navegador. Yo hace 10 años que no veo esta tecnología, pero hasta donde recuerdo, tenía que ver con el árbol que generaba, por ejemplo `ctl00_Contenido_btnDatos` se refiere al botón `btnDatos` que tiene un padre `Contenido` que a su vez tiene un padre `ctl00`, pero resulta que puede existir cierto dinamismo en la creación de los elementos, por que el árbol puede cambiar. Con el auge de JQuery se comenzó a trabajar mucho del lado del cliente y este era un problema frecuenta en aquella época

Comment: Tenes algún error en consola?

Comment: Hola @Trauma, tanto tiempo! Si te fijas en el arbol completo hasta el `input` vas a poder ver el modal esta dentro de OTRO `iframe`, por lo que para encontrarlo deberías hacer algo como `document.getElementById('div_busc').querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('ctl00_Contenido_txtRC2')`

Comment: para referenciar el "window" de un iframe usar `contentWindow` ver [`var soyTuHijo = document.getElementById('elIframe').contentWindow;`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/349286/81450)

Comment: @Marcos ¡ Hola maestro ! Mucho tiempo, si. No te lo vas a creer, pero ni se me ocurrió que pudiera haber un `<iframe>` dentro de la página ... me estoy volviendo viejo :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunos problemas

- El id es `ctl00_Contenido_txtRC2` no `ctl00$Contenido$txtRC2`
- EL modal está en un iframe
- Debes usar `contentWindow`

Por ejemplo para llegar al input, debes hacer:

```
win.contentWindow.document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById( "ctl00_Contenido_txtRC2" )
```

Para asegurar que el iframe sea el que debe puedes hacer:

```
const innerIframeDoc = win.contentWindow.document.querySelector("iframe[src='../CYCBienInmueble/OVCBusqueda.aspx?from=NuevoVisor&pest='")?.contentWindow?.document;

if(innerIframeDoc){
  const input = innerIframeDoc.getElementById( "ctl00_Contenido_txtRC2" );
  const button = innerIframeDoc.getElementById( "ctl00_Contenido_btnDatos" );
}
```

Y ya que los Id en asp.net son generados de forma dinámica (a menos que explícitamente se haya declarado lo contrario, y eso no lo sabemos). Posiblemente también debamos asegurarnos de llegar correctamente al `input` y al `button`

```
const innerIframeDoc = win.contentWindow.document.querySelector("iframe[src='../CYCBienInmueble/OVCBusqueda.aspx?from=NuevoVisor&pest='")?.contentWindow?.document;

if(innerIframeDoc){
  const input = innerIframeDoc.querySelector("#refcat2 input");
  const button = innerIframeDoc.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
}
```

Para el caso del input, vamos primero a `#refcat2` el cual es un Id estatico, luego obtenemos el primer y unico input que es hijo de él

Para el botón, simplemente `input[type=submit]`, ya que está tecnología (webforms) solo permite un formulario (razón por la cual usaron iframe), entonces cualquier `submit` nos vale