# ¿Se puede fusionar WordPress y Drupal?

Tags: wordpress, drupal

Tengo que fusionar un sitio web realizado en **WordPress** y **Drupal**, intente insertar un iframe en WordPress mandando llamar un sitio de **Drupal** pero creo que al parecer no funciona de esta manera, ya que me aparece el siguiente error:

`La página ha rechazado la conexión.`

¿Hay algún plugin o alguna forma de poder integrarlo?

La forma en como estoy insertando el iframe en wordPress de la siguiente manera:

```
<iframe src="https://dominio/drupal" title="Pagina de inicio"></iframe>
```

Lo ingreso en el wordpress utilizando la herramienta de "Html puro", el objetivo de esto es poder mostrar en wordprees un nodo de informacion de drupal, ese nodo es un contenedor de información estadístico.

Investigue y encontre que en el documento **wp-content/themes/NOMBRE_TEMA** en el archivo functions.php agregarle lo siguiente:

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'add_header_xframeoptions' );
function add_header_xframeoptions() {
header( 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN' );
}
```

Pero tampoco funciona :(

Comment: están en el mismo dominio?

Comment: Si, se encuentran en el mismo dominio  @aloMalbarez

Comment: para darle un poco de forma a la pregunta da click en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/364838/edit) y agrega las url de ambas instalaciones  anonimizandolas onda `www.midominio.mitld/miwordpress`. el iframe cómo lo has insertado? incluir el código también anonimizado que es útil para dar un ejemplo. y si podes resumir cual es el objetivo: un node de drupal en una pagina de wordpress? en un post? en un widget? etc...

Comment: @aloMalbarez Ya agregue un poquito de información adicional, no tengo mucha informaron la verdad desconozco si eso se pueda realizar, es hasta el momento lo que se me ha ocurrido.

Comment: el action le dice al wordpress que le comunique al navegador que puede ser mostrado en un iframe del mismo origen ( protocolo:dominio:puerto ) tendrías que encontrar la configuración para hacer lo mismo en drupal, que versión de drupal es? por lo pronto lo que podes hacer es editar o crear un `.htaccess` en la carpeta de instalación de drupal y agregarle `Header set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"`

Comment: * para el `.htaccess` un estandar mas nuevo es `Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors: 'self' otrodominio.com"` donde self es el mismo protocolo://dominio:puerto y otrodominio.com es una lista de dominios autorizados separados por espacios ( opcional )

Comment: @aloMalbarez la versión  de drupal 8.6.2 y esta montado en Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, y el wordpress esta en windows server

Comment: están en diferentes subdominios? o tenes montado un share/virtualización de win/ubuntu?

Comment: @aloMalbarez Se encuentra montado en diferentes subdominios, realice una prueba clonando el proyecto Drupal en la misma IP de la pagina montada en Wordpress pero me marca lo mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema de same origin es que debe ser el ***mismo origen completamente***, esto significa :

- mismo protocolo `http` o `https`
- mismo subdominio `www.midominio.mitld` o `drupal.midominio.mitld`
- mismo puerto `80` se asume para `http` y `443` para `https`

Por lo cual si están en diferentes dominios o subdominios hay que ser explícito en quién puede framear la página.

En este ejemplo tenemos un wordpress en `http://www.midominio.mitld` y un drupal en `http://drupal.midominio.mitld/`

La forma de que en wordpress ( o un html ) que está en el dominio `http://www.midominio.mitld` puedas insertar un `<iframe>` de una página de drupal ( o un html ) que está en el (sub)dominio `http://drupal.midominio.mitld` onda:

```html
<iframe src=http://drupal.midominio.mitld width=100% height=920></iframe>
```

Es añadiendo al `.htaccess` que está en la carpeta raíz del dominio `http://drupal.midominio.mitld` ( en la carpeta raíz de la instalación de drupal ), que según tu configuración puede ser `/var/www/.htaccess` ( en mi caso es `/var/www/drupal/.htaccess` ):

- una directiva para sacar el sameorigin que se envía por default en la mayoría de los apache
- otra directiva que permite al dominio de wordpress como ancestro.

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://www.midominio.mitld;"
```

Las agregas al principio así las toma antes que nada.

> Lo de ancestro es porque un dominio A puede insertar un iframe de otro dominio B que a su vez inserta un iframe de ootro dominio C que a su vez inserta un iframe de nuestro dominio, filtrando por ancestro no hay que andar pensando en toda la cadena posible de iframeados.

- al mezclar `http` y `https` hay que tener en cuenta que si el que carga está en `https` va a dar errores y no va a cargar scripts de las urls que están en `http`
- el alto del iframe está fijo pues no se puede acceder a los elementos del iframe con javascript por ser de otro (sub)dominio, para lograr aumentar el alto del iframe segun el alto de la página cargada tendrías que implementar algo con la api de mensajes como en este ejemplo [Modificar elementos de pagina padre iframe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/208452/81450) , básicamente en el onload de la page drupal se emite un mensaje fijado al dominio de wordpress contándole cual es el alto del documento y wordpress que tiene un escuchador de mensajes cuando lo recibe ajusta el alto del iframe, oculta una animación de preload, etc.